# graphically array in tkinter

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, tkinter

I am working on a Project named Linear and Binary search with GUI in Python and I have written a function to get index number of array given by user through linear search Algorithm but its not working properly suggest the improvements.

I also want to add graphically process of this Algorthim.
here is the project

> Simulator ,graphically showing linear and Binary search. This simulator asks you to select the size of array,then ,graphically that number of boxes and you can then insert data into those boxes. It only allows you to insert data into first index at first,then it enables the second box to insert data into and so. It then asks user what data want to search and graphically shows the searching process and finally display the result.

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()
root.title("Linear Search")
root.geometry("1200x600")

def Linear():
    x=root.snum.get()
    for i in range(len(box_list)):
        if box_list[i]==x:
            return i
    return -1
    result=tk.Label(root,text=i)
    result.pack()

def ApplytoLabel():
    xx=size.get()
    for i in range(xx):
        element = box_list[i].get() 
        ArrayLabel=tk.Label(root,text="Array Element: " + element,font="Arial 12 bold",bg="red",fg="white",bd="5")
        ArrayLabel.pack(side="left")

        #Search Element
    text2=tk.Label(root,text="Number to search:",
                   font="Arial 10 bold",fg="blue",pady="10",anchor="w")
    text2.pack(side="left")

    snum=tk.IntVar()

    SearchNum=tk.Entry(root,textvariable=snum)
    SearchNum.pack(side="left")

    LinearSearch=tk.Button(root,text="Linear Search",command=Linear)
    LinearSearch.pack(side="left")

box_list = []   

def Boxes():
    xx=size.get()
    for i in range(xx):        
        box=tk.Entry(root,font="Arial 10 bold",bd="5",width="5")
        box.pack(side="left")
        box_list.append(box)    
    ApplytoLabel1=tk.Button(root,text="Submit To Array",command=ApplytoLabel)
    ApplytoLabel1.pack(side="left")



Array = tk.Frame(root)
Array.pack()

text1=tk.Label(Array,text="Enter the Size of Array:",
               font="Arial 10 bold",fg="blue")
text1.pack()

size=tk.IntVar()

ArraySize=tk.Entry(Array,textvariable=size)
ArraySize.pack()

SizeofArray=tk.Button(Array,text="Submit",command=Boxes)
SizeofArray.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What does "not working properly" mean? Are you getting errors? If so, what are they? If not, what is it doing, and how is it different than what you expect it to do?

Comment: Algorithm is not working I want the Array index of Number to Search given by the user..

Comment: I want to add linear and binary search in this program for getting output on GUI

Answer (score 0):

First I need to say that your use of Array is very confusing. An `Array` is a built in method so you need to use some other terminology for what you are doing. I have cleaned up your code a bit and made a few needed changes to get the functionality out of it I think you are looking for. That said please take the time to read up on [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide. It will make it much easier for others to read your code.

One of the key factors why your code is not doing what you want it to do is you are missing `global` statements for `snum` and `box_list`. These 2 will be needed to get everything to do what you want.

Next you do not need `return` in your `linear()` function as you call this function from a button and nothing being returned can be used like this.

There are a lot of places in your code where you are assigning widgets to a variable name when it is not actually needed. I have cleaned these up as well.

Let me know if you have any questions:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Linear Search")
root.geometry("1200x600")
box_list = []   

def linear():
    index_list = []
    global snum, box_list
    x = snum.get()
    for i in range(len(box_list)):
        if box_list[i].get() == str(x):
            index_list.append(i)
    print(index_list)
    tk.Label(root, text=index_list).pack()

def applyto_label():
    global snum, box_list
    xx = size.get()
    for i in range(xx):
        tk.Label(root, text="Array Element: {}".format(box_list[i].get() ),
                 font="Arial 12 bold", bg="red", fg="white", bd="5").pack(side="left")

    tk.Label(root,text="Number to search:", font="Arial 10 bold",
             fg="blue", pady="10", anchor="w").pack(side="left")
    snum = tk.IntVar()
    tk.Entry(root, textvariable=snum).pack(side="left")
    tk.Button(root,text="Linear Search",command=linear).pack(side="left")

def Boxes():
    global snum, box_list
    xx = size.get()
    for _ in range(xx):        
        box_list.append(tk.Entry(root, font="Arial 10 bold", bd="5", width="5"))
        box_list[-1].pack(side="left")
    tk.Button(root ,text="Submit To Array", command=applyto_label).pack(side="left")

arr_frame = tk.Frame(root)
arr_frame.pack()
tk.Label(arr_frame, text="Enter the Size of Array:", font="Arial 10 bold", fg="blue").pack()
size = tk.IntVar()
array_size = tk.Entry(arr_frame, textvariable=size)
array_size.pack()
tk.Button(arr_frame, text="Submit", command=Boxes).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]